# QuickSorting a Collection of classes using mutiple sort keys, is this possible?

Tags: excel, vba

I have amended a QuickSort algorithm I found online, that sorts a Collection. It is here, https://excelmacromastery.com/excel-vba-collections/#Sorting_a_Collection, my thanks to its author.

My version of this, which works, sorts a Collection of classes by a sort key contained within the class. What I would like to do is extend this algorithm to sort the collection by a second key, also contained within the class. How can I go about this? I've hard-coded the sort key, which probably needs to be parameterised. Here is my code:

```
Sub ClassQuickSort(coll As Collection, first As Long, last As Long)

    Dim vCentreVal As Variant

    Dim lTempLow As Long
    Dim lTempHi As Long
    lTempLow = first
    lTempHi = last

    Dim clsTemporaryError As clsError, clsLowError As clsError, clsHiError As clsError
    Dim clsSingleError As clsError

    Set clsSingleError = coll.Item((first + last) \ 2)
    vCentreVal = clsSingleError.variable_name

    Do While lTempLow <= lTempHi

        Do While coll.Item(lTempLow).variable_name < vCentreVal And lTempLow < last
          lTempLow = lTempLow + 1
        Loop

        Do While vCentreVal < coll.Item(lTempHi).variable_name And lTempHi > first
          lTempHi = lTempHi - 1
        Loop

        If lTempLow <= lTempHi Then

          ' Swap values
          Set clsTemporaryError = coll.Item(lTempLow)

          coll.Add coll.Item(lTempHi), After:=lTempLow
          coll.Remove lTempLow

          coll.Add clsTemporaryError, Before:=lTempHi
          coll.Remove lTempHi + 1

          ' Move to next positions
          lTempLow = lTempLow + 1
          lTempHi = lTempHi - 1

        End If

  Loop

  If first < lTempHi Then ClassQuickSort coll, first, lTempHi
  If lTempLow < last Then ClassQuickSort coll, lTempLow, last

End Sub
```

clsError has 6 members, as follows:

```
Public filename As String
Public SysID_Data As Integer
Public PlanReference_Data As String
Public MemberReference_Data As String
Public variable_name As String
Public errortype As String
```